# How to gloss a possessive suffix?

Tags: interlinear-gloss

I'm new to glossing with the [Leipzig rules](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/pdf/Glossing-Rules.pdf). In Hebrew, one can attach possessive suffixes to nouns, as in:

> *sūsām*
>   *sūs-Ø-ām*
>   horse-m.sg-m.3pl
>   "their horse"

I'm afraid this can get confusing when the glosses for the gender/number suffix and the possessive suffix are the same:

> *sūsō*
>   *sūs-Ø-ō*
>   horse-m.sg-m.3sg
>   "his horse"

How can I indicate which is the possessive suffix? Is this what the poss(essive) abbreviation is for, i.e., should I use horse-m.sg-poss.m.3sg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're exactly right that that is what the POSS (possessive) abbreviation is for. Have a look at example (21) given under Rule 5A in the version of the Leipzig Glossing Rules you link to:

> Belhare
>   *ne-ea-khim-chin-yuNNa*
>   DEM-LOC1SG.**POSS**-house-PL3NSG-be.NPST
>   DEM-LOC1s**POSS**-house-PL3ns-be.NPST
>   'Here are my houses.'

Note, however, the order is 1SG.POSS rather than POSS.1SG in this case.